# What is the best web editor and server for PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, web-mapping, editing

I'm looking for a web editor (similar to OpenStreetMap) that works with a map server (PostGIS). This should permit editing and creation of new structures on a map.

What is the best option?

Comment: can you clarify your question - e.g. postgis is a database not a map server. Are you wedded to postgis as your db? what exactly are you trying to achieve? do you have a client in mind or are standards important?

Comment: I would like to work with postgis as database. And I want to create a map server for traffic simulation which allow add and edit traffic symbols. I don't have any client in mind.

Comment: How do you define best? Easiest to set up? Easiest to use?

Comment: Easiest to use and nice looking

Answer (score 7):

you can check out OpenLayers Editor from http://ole.geops.de/.

[image: mapedit]

> OpenLayers Editor is a web-based tool for easy and precise creation of
>   spatial data. It is build purely with HTML and JavaScript and thus
>   runs on the desktop and mobile devices without plug-ins. General
>
> ```
> Based on OpenLayers
> Easily customizable and extensible
> Small and fast
> Open Source
> ```
>
> Editor
>
> ```
> Supports point, path and polygon geometry types
> Vector layer support (for example WFS)
> Snapping to existing features, guide lines or features from external data sources
> CAD-like feature construction
> Undo and redo
> Modify geometries
> Drag geometries
> Draw hole into polygons
> ```
>
> Server-side geometry processing
>
> ```
> Split polygons and lines
> Merge polygons
> Clean and validate geometries
> Includes Drupal and Zend Framework integration
> Based on PostGIS geometry processing
> ```

---

Example

```
editor = new OpenLayers.Editor(map, {
    activeControls: ['SnappingSettings', 'SplitFeature', 'MergeFeature', 'CleanFeature'],
    featureTypes: ['polygon', 'path', 'point']
});
editor.startEditMode();
```

i hope it helps you....

Comment: Did you see that @Mapperz already posted this suggestion for OpenLayers?

Comment: This is not the same as mapperzs answer

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

The OpenGeo Suite has a web editor in the form of [GeoExplorer](https://github.com/opengeo/GeoExplorer). Just add your **PostGIS** data to the Geoserver component. [Load the GeoServer layers in GeoExplorer and edit away.](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webmaps/easypublish/index.html)

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can add and edit symbols/icons using the Layer Styles option.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it must be a web editor then GeoDjango comes with this functionality. The admin feature permits basic editing of map features.  It is possible to incorporate the built-in editing functions into your own pages.

Answer (score 1):

*Openlayers* comes with editing tools
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/editingtoolbar.html

If your know drupal then there is a nice **OpenLayers Editor** (beta3)

> OpenLayers Editor is a web-based tool for easy and precise creation of
>   spatial data. It is build purely with HTML and JavaScript and thus
>   runs on the desktop and mobile devices without plug-ins. This module
>   simply adds an additional behavior to the OpenLayers module
>   characterized by the following features.

http://drupal.org/project/ole