# Web based spatial data editor

Tags: editing, web-service, security, crowdsourcing, community

Is possible to set up web access to GIS data such that a user could login and see the collected data and be allowed to suggest/draw changes but not be able to edit the data files?

My idea is that community members could see data that has been collected through land use interviews, then be able to suggest changes to the project maps through a web based editor. A GIS tech would then review the suggestion to see if the change would be appropriate.

One issue we have is that our data is considered highly proprietary and confidential. So security is very important.

Comment: In addition to commercial software, it's possible to write to write application for that, using open source components like OpenLayers and GeoServer. There are also lot of existing applications, take a look here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43477/what-is-the-best-web-editor-and-server-for-postgis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should check out Geodjango and [GeographicAdmin](http://code.google.com/p/geodjango-basic-apps/wiki/GeographicAdminQuickStart) which has lots of capabilities at spatial datas.with django in admin panel, you can control users permission as which model user will see or can change.

[image: geodjango]

beside this you can check out [Cartaro](http://cartaro.org/) - Geospatial CMS too.

> Cartaro is the web mapping platform that brings the power of the best
>   open source geospatial components into a content management system.

Answer (score 0):

ESRI's [ArcGIS Server Standard/Advanced](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/features/functionality-table) allows web based editing of data.

Comment: Can I limit functionality such that the general population can only propose edits rather than actually make them?

Comment: Hmmm...not out of the box!
I guess you're not looking for full fldged online editing, but simply markers proposing the changes...am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yeah that is correct. I'd like to have people be able propose edit in the same way one would normally work in an editor such as drawing polygons, lines and points. But I need these edits to be curated by a GIS technician.

Comment: Well then you do not need to enable editing at all...just allow users to add "redlines/text" proposing the changes.